# Avro C++ build error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, avro

in my current c++ project I need to use avro c++ serializer. Firstly I built boost 1.6.2 and based on it I build via Visual Studio 2015 the Avro-cpp.sln file as it is mentioned in avro relevant site. In my code I'm using the following include files

```
 #include "avro/DataFile.hh"   
 #include "avro/Compiler.hh"   
 #include "avro/ValidSchema.hh"   
 #include "avro/Schema.hh"  
 #include "avro/Generic.hh"    
 #include "avro/Specific.hh"
```

However when I'm trying to build the project I get the following errors

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall avro::DataFileWriterBase::syncIfNeeded(void)  
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall avro::DataFileWriterBase::DataFileWriterBase(char const *,class avro::ValidSchema const &,unsigned int,enum avro::Codec)"  
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall avro::DataFileWriterBase::~DataFileWriterBase(void)" (??1DataFileWriterBase@avro@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void * __thiscall avro::DataFileWriterBase::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)"  
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall avro::DataFileWriterBase::close(void)"  
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall avro::DataFileWriterBase::close(void)"  
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl avro::compileJsonSchema(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class avro::ValidSchema &)"  
error LNK2019: "public: void __thiscall avro::DataFileWriterBase::flush(void)"
```

I assume that the linker does not find the definition of the the specific classes DataFileWriterBase and compileJsonSchema .Since I'haven't worked with AVRO before I'd like to ask what libraries should I add in order for this problem to be solved? Do I have to insert the relevant cc files in my source code?  I also built from Avro-cpp.sln file the avrocpp.dll and the avrocpp_s.dll, included them in my project but the problem remained the same. Does anyone has any idea since I haven't found any hint in either avro site or similar forums.

Hi again these are the new findings

I searched thoroughly and I probably found a possible cause , but I don't know how to move on. The problem seems to be in file Config.hh

```
 #ifndef avro_Config_hh
 #define avro_Config_hh

  // Windows DLL suport

  #ifdef _WIN32
  #pragma warning (disable: 4275 4251)

  #if defined(AVRO_DYN_LINK)
  #ifdef AVRO_SOURCE
  # define AVRO_DECL __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
  # define AVRO_DECL __declspec(dllimport)
  #endif  // AVRO_SOURCE
  #endif  // AVRO_DYN_LINK
  #endif  // _WIN32

  #ifndef AVRO_DECL
  #define AVRO_DECL
   #endif

  #endif
```

I think that AVRO_DYN_LINK is not defined and __declspec(dllexport) is not executed. So AVRO_DECL is defined and even though library lib is build with the function definitions they are exported and the error occur. Do you have any hint on the above analysis?

Comment: you are right about the linker, you never told it what to link against. Did your Avro build produced any .lib files (import library)? that would be the file you need to link against, and your app would end up using avrocpp.dll in runtime

Comment: @Oleg Bogdanov in the release version it created avrocpp.dll, avrocpp.exp, avrocpp.lib and also avrocpp_s.lib which I assume is the static version. I added the first three in the include directories of my project but nothing happened. What do I do wrong ?

Comment: they dont belong to include directories, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822.aspx

Comment: @Oleg Bogdanov I added the lib file in the linker input as well as the
 boost libs that existed in avrocpp project linker:  

boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_62.lib ,boost_system-vc140-mt-1_62.lib  
boost_program_options-vc140-mt-1_62.lib, boost_iostreams-vc140-mt-1_62.lib , boost_regex-vc140-mt-1_62.lib.

But the problem remained. Any other hint ?

Comment: can you post screenshot of linker input somewhere

Comment: @Oleg Bogdanov sorry for the delay, but I got new findings that you can see above.

Comment: can you check if DataFileWriter is even added into avro's solution, it looks as if it was never compiled